# Is there any joke (or) sarcasm in it?

Tags: meaning, jokes

In the movie Wrath of Man (2021), there is a scene where an armoured truck is robbed by heavily armed individuals dressed as construction workers:

> Man 1: **They don't pay you enough to act a fool; let's go!**

Is there any joke (or) sarcasm in it?

Comment: It's not a joke; it's sarcasm.

Comment: @Lambie Please give me the meaning of that sarcasm here.

Comment: Would you want to act like a fool in a public place? I assume you do not want to. Now, if someone gave you a lot of money to act like a fool in public, would  you??

Comment: Presumably 'Man 1' is 'Security Man 1' and not 'Robber Man 1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the robber is trying to convince the armored truck driver not to resist the robbery. He is telling the driver that he doesn't get paid enough to risk his life. It's not sarcasm, it's just a way of threatening his life if he continues to resist.

Comment: Of course it is sarcasm. But that does not mean it isn't serious.